# Script not working in printWindow command

Tags: javascript, popup

I am creating a popup window with a button that doesn't work when clicked.  Below is my javascript:

```
      function showPic(pic_id, user_pic, name, caption, date) {

        span = getTimeSpan(date);

            printWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=650, height=710, scrollbars');

        printWindow.document.open();
        var htmlcode = "<img src='" + pic_id + "'> </br><table border=0 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=1><tr><td align=left valign=top><img src='" + user_pic + "' width=50></td><td align=left valign=top>" + span + "&nbsp; - <b>" + name + ":</b> &nbsp;" + caption;
        htmlcode += "</br><input type=\"button\" value=\"See all photos\" onclick=\"showUserPhotos('" + name + "')\" /></td></tr></table>";
        htmlcode += "<script>function showUserPhotos(user_name) { alert(\"username=\" + user_name)}";

        printWindow.document.write(htmlcode);
        printWindow.document.close();
    }
```

You will notice that I do not have an end of "script" tag in the logic above as the program will give me an error if I use it.  The showUserPhotos does not execute when clicking on the button in the popup.  Is there a way to execute script from within a popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your window first. In other words use `window.open('urlofexistingpage.html')`. Open a page that already has JavaScript on it. If that doesn't work for you and you want to dynamically create the window script then you'll need to use `jQuery.ajax()` or the `XMLHttpRequest` Object.

Comment: I want to make it a dynamic window so if I include the javascript logic in the existing page I wish to open, how do I append the dynamic code to the page before I write it?

Comment: I think it is easier to just use the window.open command and pass parameters to the window if I want to make it dynamic.  Thanks for your suggestions.